Not enough permissions to access: me.GET.NO_VERSION
i am using this api
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me
and getting response
{
"status": 403,
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
"message": "Not enough permissions to access: me.GET.NO_VERSION"
}
i have already added scope email profile and openid
i am expecting the user profile info but not retrieving by using v2/me
